# Can TortoiseGit, Git Extensions, and SmartGit coexist on Windows 7 64bit?

Tags: git, tortoisegit, git-extensions, smartgit

I have just installed TortoiseGit 1.6.5, Git Extensions 2.21, and SmartGit 2.0.4 on Windows 7 64bit thirty minutes ago.

Would this cause any compatibility issues?

---

**Update:**

I think TortoiseGit and Git Extensions should coexist well, because by default [Git Source Control Provider](http://gitscc.codeplex.com/) displays commands of both TortoiseGit and Git Extensions in the context menu.

From official website of [Git Source Control Provider](http://gitscc.codeplex.com/):

[image]

Comment: Why do you need so many UI's? In fact, why not just use git itself... However note that Git is made by linux people so normally theres no coexistance problems like Microsoft products tend to suffer from (ie registry conflicts. Normally its all self contained since its just a set prefix and make install)

Comment: @mathepic: Thanks for the reply. I just start using git today, so not quite sure which GUI client is suitable for me. I love the icon overlay of TortoiseGit but also love the browser in Git Extensions and SmartGit.

Comment: The only possible problem I can think of could be when using different versions of Git on the same repository. For SmartGit you can configure the Git version to use, so it can be used in combination with every other client.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not uncommon to use different clients for different purposes, as they all have their strengths and weaknesses.  Multiple clients generally work very well together.  Just keep in mind you might have to do a rescan/refresh for one client to notice changes made by another.  I have seen the occasional problem where tortoisegit is doing a caching operation that momentarily locks out the other clients.  It was annoying enough for me to uninstall tortoisegit, but we have 60,000 versioned files so it may be more noticeable on our codebase than others.  Just keep that in mind if you see error messages about locks you didn't expect.